# "Network is unreachable" when forwarding traffic to virtual ethernet adapter in separate namespace

Tags: linux, networking

My goal is to setup a separate namespace on my Linux server that I can use for an OpenVPN connection and then a VirtualBox host.

---

So far I have followed these steps:

1. Setup a cronjob `@reboot /home/ubuntu/startupscripts/rootscripts.sh`
2. Inside the shell script, perform: [(Adapted from here)](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/09/04/introducing-linux-network-namespaces/)
    `# Setup VPN
    ip netns add vpnspace
    ip link add vpnopen type veth peer name vpnbind
    ip link set vpnopen netns vpnspace
    ip netns exec vpnspace /sbin/ifconfig vpnopen 10.0.0.1/24 up` [(See question)](https://serverfault.com/questions/897658/ifconfig-up-does-not-execute-from-cron)
    `/sbin/ifconfig vpnbind up`**
3. Added the iptables rules below and reconfigured iptables-persistent [(Adapted from)](https://serverfault.com/questions/431593/iptables-forwarding-between-two-interface) [(See question)](https://serverfault.com/questions/897710/iptables-rules-dissappear-when-manually-adding-a-nat-rule-to-iptables-persistent)
    `-A FORWARD -i vpnbind -o ens3 -j ACCEPT
    -A FORWARD -i ens3 -o vpnbind -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
    -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

** *I added this step because `sudo lshw -C network` showed the network connection was not active. [(See question)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/889880/cannot-find-device-eth0)*

---

When I attempt `sudo ip netns exec vpnspace ping 8.8.8.8` from the terminal, I receive error message `connect: Network is unreachable`. I am not sure where to go from here.

Below are various outputs. Please say in the comments if you would like me to add others.

---

**ifconfig**:

```
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:XXX.XXX.XXX.92  Bcast:XXX.225.222.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:44943 errors:16 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:16
          TX packets:467 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3042544 (3.0 MB)  TX bytes:49351 (49.3 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:100 (100.0 B)  TX bytes:100 (100.0 B)

vpnbind   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet6 addr: XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**sudo ip netns exec vpnspace ifconfig**:

```
vpnopen   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 36:28:6f:74:1b:72  
          inet addr:10.0.0.1  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: XXXX::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:648 (648.0 B)
```

---

**ip link show**:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: vpnbind@if4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

**sudo ip netns exec vpnspace ip link show**:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
4: vpnopen@if3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
```

---

**/etc/network/interfaces**:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Preconfigured by my VPS provider
auto ens3
iface ens3 inet static
        address XXX.XXX.XXX.92
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast +
        up route -A inet add XXX.XXX.XXX.1 dev ens3
        up route -A inet add default gw XXX.XXX.XXX.1 dev ens3
iface ens3 inet6 manual
        pre-down ip -6 addr flush dev ens3 scope global || :
```

---

**Updated Script**

```
ip netns add vpnspace
ip link add vpnopen type veth peer name vpnbind

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ens3/forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/vpnbind/forwarding

ip link set vpnbind up

ip link set vpnopen netns vpnspace
ip -n vpnspace addr add 10.0.0.1 dev vpnopen
ip -n vpnspace addr add 10.0.0.254 broadcast 10.0.0.255 dev vpnopen
ip -n vpnspace link set vpnopen up
ip -n vpnspace route add default via 10.0.0.254
```

Comment: Of all the outputs, `/etc/network/interfaces` is the only one I haven't added manual configuration to. Is it necessary when forwarding traffic from one interface to another?

Answer (score 0):

You have the default route on `vpnspace` pointing to itself. You should add the address `10.0.0.254` to `vpnbind` instead of `vpnopen`.

Also you have assigned all of 10.0.0.0/8 to your veth pair which will cause problems reaching other hosts in that address range.